# Using the sinc integral to estimate $\pi$

Tags: calculus

We know that
$$
\frac{\pi}{2} = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx
$$
By separating our integral and using a substitution we obtain:
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx &= \int_0^1 \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx + \int_1^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx \, + \int_0^1 \frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{x}dx
\end{align}
Using taylor series:
$$
\frac{\pi}{2} = \int_0^1 \left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n+1)!} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!x^{2n+2}} \right]
$$
Evaluating:
$$
\frac{\pi}{2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n-(-1)^n}{(2n+1)(2n+1)!}
$$
Meaning that
$$
\frac{\pi}{2} = 0\,?
$$
Where did I go wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Careful about the Taylor Series part.

Comment: The Taylor series for $\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is not uniformly convergent on $(0,1)$, meaning the swap of the integral and summation was not justified.

Comment: @NinadMunshi: Please post an answer because the currently existing one is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it is wrong is that Taylor series for $\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is not uniformly convergent on $(0, 1)$.

Analogy:

You could say that

$$1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... = -\frac{1}{12}$$

*if $1+2+3+4+...$ is convergent*, but it is not, so the equality does not hold.

Comment: Your first statement is wrong. The taylor series for $\sin(1/x)$ **is** convergent for every $x∈(0,1)$. It isn't uniformly convergent, but it is certainly convergent. If you don't know the technical details, please don't post an answer otherwise you would mislead the asker and other readers. Thank you.

Comment: @user21820 Got it. So because a user makes a mistake, they shouldn't post an answer.  I got your reasoning.

Comment: It's not an accidental mistake. You brought up an example of a non-convergent sum, which is *completely irrelevant*, fully confirming your conceptual mistake. My point is that you should not post answers outside your area of expertise, for the reason I stated, **not** "because you made a mistake". Please don't stuff words into my mouth that I didn't say. I hope that you do value mathematical correctness more than your response to me makes me feel.

Comment: @user21820 BTW, some people think that all people who answer on this site are "stupid" people. If they were actually real mathematicians, they wouldn't be "wasting their time" on this site.

Comment: Honestly, I cannot figure out what you are trying to convey in your responses. Is it so difficult to admit your errors and change your ways without throwing barbed retorts? I personally delete answers with careless errors once someone points it out to me. I only post answers in my area of expertise. This way we maintain the quality of answers on Math SE. Why wouldn't you want to have that? I frankly see no reason to talk about the silly opinions that you brought up; there are many *professional mathematicians* who post tons of valuable answers here, such as Asaf Karagila, Noah Schweber, ...

Comment: @user21820 I do not know of any of these mathematicians